# Deploy Windows Store App From Command Line

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-store-apps, automated-deployment

Often times when I am building medium to large scale applications, I end up writing a powershell script or batch file to build all of my dependent assemblies, etc.  Lately I have been working on a windows store app, and the script approach is working just fine, except for one final part. I can't figure out how I can not only build, but also deploy my app to my local machine.  I can do it in Visual Studio via this menu option:

[image: deployment!]

But that means I have to go to Visual Studio and do it manually which kind of defeats the purpose of an automated build.  Does anyone have any clue as to how I can get this 'deploy' functionality from the command line??  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try the same behavior as with [sideloading apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx):

> At the Windows PowerShell prompt, run the following commands, where
>   SampleApp is the path and name of the package file you created (e.g.,
>   MySample_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_Debug.appx):
>
> import-module appx
>
> add-appxpackage “SampleApp”

Comment: I didn't create any package files / how do I do that?

Comment: So, you have no build script yet?

Comment: I do.  Everything builds just fine.

Comment: What do you have as a final output of your Windows Store app?

Comment: An executable.  What else would I have?  I get the feeling we are not on the same page.

Comment: Check the AppxPackage folder in your solution folder.

Comment: There is no AppxPackage folder in the solution directory.

Comment: Windows Store apps is .appx packages. Try to enable building the appx package in your script. I think that there will be two additional options: package for store and package for side-loading. You need the second. Package for store will have .appxupload extension.

Comment: That gets back to the original question.  How do I build the appx package?

Comment: Use [MakeAppx.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx).